# Cannot run .exe from Task Scheduler same as in PowerShell window

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run an .exe from within a PowerShell (PS) script that is started from Task Scheduler (TS).  The .exe does not execute, although it is *listed* in Get-Process.

If I run the script manually from a PS window, the .exe works, and it is also listed in Get-Process.

There is a difference though - in the Get-Process headers there is a column of "SI", and the working instance has a "1". The non-working instance has a "0".  I see no mention of "SI" anywhere on the internet.

I've tried several types of invocation for the .exe, and they all work (fail) the same, e.g. `Start-Process`, `&` and `Invoke-Expression`.  The .exe has also been run with (and without) `-verb runas` in all attempts.

I believe, manually, it takes the Admin-window privileges and works as designed, however with Task Scheduler it has lesser privileges even though the task is run with "highest privileges".  Or it is special handling to prevent malicious code from being executed from a script - which is exactly how it is acting.

Initiating the .exe manually from Explorer also works fine.

I am lost in the Local Policy, Group Policy, UAC, and running this .exe with granted permissions or users, so I stopped short of haphazardly changing any those (and opening up wide vulnerability).

Help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Win10 Pro, PowerShell v5

Comment: Use `Start-Transcript "c:\logs\log.txt"` and then run the script the way it works manually. Look at the log and look what it looks like when it works. Now use `Start-Transcript` in the top of the PowerShell script that is not working and then once you believe it has had enough time to complete, look at the transcript log file and see if there are any errors to dig into. Try to run the Task as `SYSTEM` plus with highest privileges  by typing in system credential Task Schedule fiiled/area labeled, `When running this task, use the following user account`.

Comment: Manually, the transcript looks like console - silent and the .exe works.  By the task, its transcript is similar i.e. silent but the .exe doesn't actually function.  I watch in another PS session with Get-Process and I see the process of each method, but it is different by "1" and "0" as described above.  It's like the .exe process is running but not functioning during the task.  I've tried with SYSTEM and Highest Privledges, and no difference.  I've also reduced UAC to "Nothing" and have enabled "As Admin" for All Users on the .exe file - no difference.  As if the task is limiting privileges.

Comment: Try running the Task Scheduler 'interactive` for 'When running the task, use the following user account` and also check the box in Task Scheduler to `Run only when user is logged on`. See if running with PowerShell via `Start-Process` rather than `&` makes any difference. Not sure if `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in the PowerShell before the execution of the exe via PS logic does it. I'd uncheck all the options to run the exe elevated, etc. and just run that per the configuration that works when running manually. Try executing just the EXE with TS directly with no PS at all.

Comment: Since you said in another comment that this is an exe that presses keyboard keystrokes (toggling scroll lock) it will need to run unders security of the interactively logged on Windows user account since it's the one logged in. Test with no `-verb runas` or anything special.

Comment: `Run only when user is logged on` made the difference. Thanks!!  I would not have ever tried that.  I have all various `Run as administrator` settings enabled and have not backed any down to test for unnecessary enablement; I'm wore out at this point, it works, and I don't see any risks. I did add a `-WindowStyle hidden` switch to the task's PowerShell execution to hide the task, and I also added an automatic Windows logon to guard against installation reboots, thus allowing the task to run. BTW, the scroll-sending .exe has been successful in keeping the computer awake throughout the task. Thx

Comment: I figured that's what the problem was based on the comment in the other post regarding it pressing keystrokes. The answer was basically to select that option specifically within Task Scheduler for it to work interactively.

Answer (score 1):

SI is Session ID.

**Session ID 0 is Non-Interactive** & used by System Services. Executables in this Session will not show up in user GUI.

Normal User gets to use Session ID 1 (or higher) & that will be Interactive in general , hence User can see the Executables in the User GUI.

In your Case , the Binary is Executing in Session ID 0 , hence not visible to User , though get_Process , tasklist , task-manager , Etc will list that.

Comment: Thanks, I get most of that.  The .exe is mine, which toggles the Scroll key every two seconds, so there is nothing to see on the monitor.  There is only the blinking keyboard light (when it is actually functioning).  The "0" and "1" differences in SI seem to indicate different deployment types.

Comment: You have the Source Code , hence you should make it write to a log file with timestamps , whether it started ok , whether keyboard light toggle went ok , Etc. Some thoughts I would Explore : (1) [[ more likely ]] It might be that Non-Interactive Session will not allow global changes to other users , including changing keyboard states & sending keyboard events , because that Non-Interactive Session has no keyboard (2) [[ less likely ]] It might be changing the local keyboard state but not the global keyboard state , hence other users can not see that.

Comment: I guess I didn't really understand as much as I thought, but I think I do now.  Running it as interactive i.e. `Run only when user is logged on` allowed the .exe to function.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: **Correct** : When running **Interactively AND with a user logged in** , it will change the keyboard state for that user , not for other users & not at the global level ! When running **Non-Interactively** , it will not even have access to the keyboard , hence it will not work !

Comment: Please edit your answer to add in for Task Scheduler to have the option selected `Run only when user is logged on` since that was the confirmed solution. While the detail you provided could be deduced to indicate that, having it stated explicitly will be more helpful to those not as tech savvy as others to decipher that option per the other things you noted in your answer. Tag me back once that's complete for a +1 and I'll delete my comment then too.